# analyze in nested object elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I am trying to run `_analyze` in ES.When i give the follwoing for non nested field i am getting response

```
GET index_v5/_analyze?field=object.@name
{
     "text": "stack overflow" 

}
```

But when i use the same for `nested` object i am getting error

```
 GET index_v5/_analyze?field=nestedobject.@name
    {
         "text": "stack overflow" 

    }
```

error:  `Request failed to get to the server (status code: 0):`

I have tried above requetes from sense plugin.

What went wrong when i give `_analyze` to nested fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `@` sign with `%40` like this and it will work. The reason is because the `@` sign is a reserved URL character.

```
GET index_v5/_analyze?field=nestedobject.%40name
{
     "text": "stack overflow" 

}
```

Comment: Gem, Worked for me